# Adding dynamic row to Birt table

Tags: birt

I have a table in Birt Report:

[image]

The requirement here is that, whenever AM is getting changed, I have to calculate sum of Sales. Similarily if the value of DM is getting changed, the sum should be done.

How can I add the "Total" row dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply create 2 table groups on AM and DM?

Comment: Thanks @Dominique. I created two groups and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dominique: you should add your comment as answer so Ashwini can accept it an everyone can see that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 table groups on AM and DM :)